# How to parse data from url in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

Is it possible to complete the given scenario in wordpress by using already existing plugins:

1. Client would be able to login to the WP site
2. Go to a place where he can paste the URL of the news item and from there site would grab elements like Title, Post Content (summary) and Image from post
3. Client can then edit some of these elements before “posting” them to the site

Comment: I doubt that this can be accomplished correctly, since different sites have different structure and as we all know, you [can't parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: use json API wordpress plugin